# "Struggle to" or "struggle with"?

Tags: prepositions

Can anyone tell me what preposition should be used after the verb 'struggle' because I've seen both versions like "struggle to" and "struggle with" ?

> A handful of other rich countries are struggling **with** opioid
>   misuse too.

> But pharmacists from hospitals outside Lagos, the commercial capital,
>   must travel there to buy morphine. Smaller hospitals struggle **to**
>   pay for the trip.

Answer (score 5):

In my completely informal opinion, you "struggle to" with a verb and "struggle with" a noun.

"I struggle to tie my shoes."
In this case struggle refers to the tying of the shoes.

"I struggle with alcohol abuse."
In this case the struggle is with alcoholism.

Comment: What about "I struggle with tying my shoes", where *tying* is a verb participle?

Comment: A good point... Maybe more clear to say that one "struggles with" a thing or action?

Comment: Yes, and maybe refer to the other usage as a "to-infinitive" verb construction. It's best to add these to your answer by re-editing it, rather than adding to comments, as this will increase your chances of positive votes and reduce the risk of downvotes (I see you've got one drive-by downvote already - with any luck they'll change their vote if you improve your answer).

Comment: @Chappo, In your sentence, tying is not a verb participle, it is a gerund or verbal noun. So, as this answer says, you struggle **with** it because it is a noun.

Comment: Seriously, 'In my informal opinion'?. Don't answer it if aint sure coz that won't help.

Comment: I was going to say exactly this. Struggle with a thing, struggle to do something.

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse purpose: struggle **to** do something. a "to infinitive" signals a purpose or reason.

WITH:

to struggle with something: there is no purpose. It merely identifies your struggle.

This is not a case of a verb "taking a preposition" as many verbs can do the same thing.

To play with a person. [to identify who is being played with]
To play to the crowd. [purpose]

Comment: What about "Struggle into"

Comment: @Kumarsadhu What about it? "I am not covering every single preposition, she said as struggled into her tight shoes."